# Python) Variable Modification

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple question, look at this code..

```
greeting_morning = "good morning"
greeting_night = "good night"

time = "morning"

print(greeting_time) # should be printing good morning
```

And this results an error..

Did you notice my problem?

I just want it to print "good morning," but it won't.

How can I properly fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`greeting_time` is a variable that does not exist. You only have these variables available:

`print(greeting_morning)` is what you need to do to get that output.